# Using sed (or anything useful) to replace strings with relative content

Tags: linux, sed, files, search, replace

Usually to replace strings across multiple files, one simply needs to use

```
sed -i 's/string1/string2/g' *
```

However, how could I use the `sed` command (or anything that works, really) to replace things strings with content relative to them. For example:

```
<td><a href="">a</a></td>
<td><a href="">abbr</a></td>
<td><a href="">address</a></td>
<td><a href="">area</a></td>
...
```

Using the example above, **what could I use to replace the text such that the result is thus:**

```
<td><a href="HTML-EX/html/a.html">a</a></td>
<td><a href="HTML-EX/html/abbr.html">abbr</a></td>
<td><a href="HTML-EX/html/address.html">address</a></td>
<td><a href="HTML-EX/html/area.html">area</a></td>
...
```

where it is replacing the double quotes `""` with the string a few characters relative to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example should work for you.

```
sed 's#<a href="">\(.*\)</a>#<a href="HTML-EX/html/\1.html">\1</a>#'
```

It first captures the text between the a tags, which is represented by the `\1` variable. Then use the variable in the result string.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i -pe 's|<a\hhref=\K "" (?=>([^<]+)</a>)|"HTML-EX/html/$1.html"|gx' *
```

Use  the lookbehind and lookahed at `""` and insert the requisite string inside these double quotes based on the lookahead capture.